# how to load retrieve form value from custom element

Tags: 8, forms

i just done build a custom element based on this tutorial: https://docs.acquia.com/articles/drupal-8-creating-elements-theming-elements-and-managing-frontend-libraries

so let say my element type is "location"

so i have:

```
$form["location"] = [
      '#type' => 'location',
      '#label' => $this->t('Supplier Location'),
      '#theme' => 'supplier_location',
];
```

so inside type location there are a couple fields (e.g. textfield, select, etc.)

the problem here is: when i submit my form, i couldn't get those value:

```
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    foreach ($form_state->getValues() as $key => $value) {
        drupal_set_message($key . ': ' . $value); // i cant catch my custom element value here T_T why?
    }    
  }
```

so apparently my custom element field value is not catched in submitform during submit, any idea why?

<s>here is my custom element class code:</s>
actually, below is the sample working code after discussion with [@clive](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2800/clive)

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\module\Element\Location.
 */

namespace Drupal\module\Element;

use Drupal\Core\Render\Element\FormElement;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Provides a location element.
 * @FormElement("location")
 */
class Location extends FormElement {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getInfo() {
    $class = get_class($this);
    return [
      '#input' => TRUE,
      '#element_validate' => [[$class, 'validateLocation']],
      '#process' => [[$class, 'processLocation'],[$class, 'processGroup']],
      '#pre_render' => [[$class, 'preRenderGroup']],
      '#theme' => 'location',
      //'#theme_wrappers' => ???, //what is theme wrappers?
    ];
  }

  /**
   * Prepare the render array for the template.
   */
  public static function processLocation(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, &$complete_form) {

    $countries = \Drupal::service('country_manager')->getList();
    $element['address'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Address: '),
        '#description' => t('Your Address'),
        '#default_value' => "",
        '#size' => 136,
        '#required' => FALSE,
        '#attributes' => [
          'id' => 'id',
          'placeholder' => 'Enter your address here',
        ]
    ];

    $element['zip'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Zip: '),
        '#description' => t('Zip Code'),
        '#default_value' => "",
        '#size' => 136,
        '#required' => FALSE,
        '#attributes' => [
          'id' => 'id',
          'placeholder' => 'Enter your Zip Code here',
        ]
    ];

    $element['city'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('City: '),
        '#description' => t('Select City'),
        '#default_value' => "",
        '#size' => 136,
        '#required' => FALSE,
        '#attributes' => [
          'id' => 'id',
          'placeholder' => 'Enter your city here',
        ]
    ];

    $element['state'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('State: '),
        '#description' => t('Select State'),
        '#default_value' => "",
        '#size' => 136,
        '#required' => FALSE,
        '#attributes' => [
          'id' => 'id',
          'placeholder' => 'Enter your State here',
        ]
    ];

    $element['country'] = [
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Country: '),
        '#options' => $countries,
        '#default_value' => '',
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#attributes' => [
          'id' => 'id',
        ]
    ];

    $element['latitude'] = [
        '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#title' => t('latitude: '),
        '#default_value' => "",
        '#attributes' => [
          'id' => 'id',
        ]
    ];

    $element['longitude'] = [
        '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#title' => t('longitude: '),
        '#default_value' => "",
        '#attributes' => [
          'id' => 'id',
        ]
    ];

    $element['zoom'] = [
        '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#title' => t('zoom: '),
        '#default_value' => "",
        '#attributes' => [
          'id' => 'id',
        ]
    ];

    // Add the library
    $element['#attached'] = ['library' => ['module/arm_location_field_library']];

    return $element;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function valueCallback(&$element, $input, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
      //what should i do here?
      return $input;
  }

  /**
   * Validation callback for a location element.
   *
   * @param array $element
   *   The form element whose value is being validated.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
   *   The current state of the form.
   * @param array $complete_form
   *   The complete form structure.
   */
  public static function validateLocation(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, &$complete_form) {
    //what should i do here?
  }

}
```

Comment: Without seeing your code it's difficult to say - what does your `valueCallback()` method look like for the custom element type?

Comment: I update the code in question

Comment: i dont have valueCallback() method, where should i put it?

Comment: It goes in the form element class, you're overriding [`FormElement::valueCallback()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!Element!FormElement.php/function/FormElement%3A%3AvalueCallback/8.2.x). Pretty sure that's what you're missing

Comment: hmm thanks, let me explore that, do you have any reference, if i may? on how to override this?

Comment: Looking at that again I think I might have been wrong. Don't have time to double-check right now, but see what the [`Datetime`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Datetime%21Element%21Datetime.php/class/Datetime/8.2.x) element does for the `valueCallback` method. That element also has multiple fields, and returns an array for the value. Might be worth trying to at least `return $input;` from your own implementation of that method to see if it has an effect

Comment: thank you, still not success :( my element is extending from RenderElement, should i extend it from formElement? i tried to extend it from formElement but it said formElement class is not found...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form element needs to extend the [`FormElement`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21FormElement.php/class/FormElement/8.2.x) class, rather than `RenderElement`.

Because of these few lines of code in [`ElementInfoManager::buildInfo`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21ElementInfoManager.php/function/ElementInfoManager%3A%3AbuildInfo/8.2.x):

```
// If this is element is to be used exclusively in a form, denote that it
// will receive input, and assign the value callback.
if ($element instanceof FormElementInterface) {
  $element_info['#input'] = TRUE;
  $element_info['#value_callback'] = array($definition['class'], 'valueCallback');
}
```

along with these in [`FormBuilder::doBuildForm`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!FormBuilder.php/function/FormBuilder%3A%3AdoBuildForm/8.2.x):

```
// Handle input elements.
if (!empty($element['#input'])) {
  $this->handleInputElement($form_id, $element, $form_state);
}
```

more generic render elements won't be considered capable of providing input, and their values won't make it into the form state.

To fix (untested):

- Replace `use Drupal\Core\Render\Element\RenderElement` with `use Drupal\Core\Render\Element\FormElement`
- Replace `@RenderElement("location")` with `@FormElement("location")` in the annotation
- Change your class to extend `FormElement`: `class Location extends FormElement`
- Rebuild the cache

Comment: Thanks,

I changed it into FormElement without valueCallback() and add #input => True in getInfo();

when i try to print, it detect the variable "location" but the value is empty

Comment: I mark you as an answer - thank you for the help, i have update my code in question for anyone who like to see it. in general it is worked, i got the value passed down. just a minor thing: if you see in my buildForm(), i use $form['location'] with type 'location', ideally you should receive the value under/inside ['location'] from $form_state->getValues(); however, what i receive is: ['location'] = empty, ['address'] = correct, ['zip'] = correct, ['city'] = correct, etc. as an individual array (not inside ['location'] array) - how to make it inside ['location']? just to make it tidy.

Comment: Adding `'#tree' => TRUE` to the element definition in `getInfo` makes sure that element values are properly wrapped inside the main element.